# Google Test test name confusion

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm really confused by what SquareTest and PosZeroNeg is representing in this example. I would expect that they are strings being passed into a function, but they aren't? I'm new to c++ so I'm not even sure what to look up since I've never seen anything like this. CLion is showing those "variable string" things as valid c++. Can someone explain what this is?

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Particle.h"

TEST (SquareTest /*test suite name*/, PosZeroNeg /*test name*/) {
    EXPECT_EQ (9.0, (3.0*2.0)); // fail, test continues
    ASSERT_EQ (0.0, (0.0));     // success
    ASSERT_EQ (9, (3)*(-3.0));  // fail, test interrupts
    ASSERT_EQ (-9, (-3)*(-3.0));// not executed due to the previous assert
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what strings and what functions are you talking about?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md)? `TEST(...)` is a macro.

Comment: Sorry. What I was talking about was the parameters of the `TEST` function. The first positional arg is the name of the test suite and the second is the name of the specific test. I don't understand what `SquareTest` and `PosZeroNeg` is in c++. It's obviously not a string, it's not a class because I'm not importing anything, so how can google test find out the name from this unknown thing? @S.M.

Comment: @Kevin I think that is what I was looking for. It didn't seem like anything else I've seen in other languages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEST` is a macro with two arguments, the macro produces the test case `SquareTest.PosZeroNeg`. It may depend on an implementation, but in this  particular example this days, `SquareTest` names a class and `PosZeroNeg` names a (static) class method, both are generated by the macro, and `SquareTest.PosZeroNeg` maps these class and method when used. Since the first macro argument is a class name, the second is a method name, they are not strings, but are identifiers, and can not contain quotes.